# How do i know if my hadoop mapreduce application is running in distributed mode

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, cluster-computing

I'm very new in hadoop mapreduce, however i install the multinode cluster but i still get a sequential excution.

How can i work out if my program is running on the other machines in the cluster or not?

This is the result of execution :

```
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx1g
16/06/07 14:49:16 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
16/06/07 14:49:19 INFO Configuration.deprecation: session.id is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.metrics.session-id
16/06/07 14:49:19 INFO jvm.JvmMetrics: Initializing JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId=
16/06/07 14:49:21 WARN mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Hadoop command-line option parsing not performed. Implement the Tool interface and execute your application with ToolRunner to remedy this.
16/06/07 14:49:21 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 3
16/06/07 14:49:22 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:3
16/06/07 14:49:23 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_local1881318657_0001
16/06/07 14:49:24 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://localhost:8080/
16/06/07 14:49:24 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_local1881318657_0001
16/06/07 14:49:24 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: OutputCommitter set in config null
16/06/07 14:49:24 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: OutputCommitter is org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter
16/06/07 14:49:24 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Waiting for map tasks
16/06/07 14:49:24 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Starting task: attempt_local1881318657_0001_m_000000_0
16/06/07 14:49:24 INFO mapred.Task:  Using ResourceCalculatorProcessTree : [ ]
16/06/07 14:49:24 INFO mapred.MapTask: Processing split: hdfs://master:9000/input/leukemia.txt:0+1172207
16/06/07 14:49:24 INFO mapred.MapTask: (EQUATOR) 0 kvi 26214396(104857584)
16/06/07 14:49:24 INFO mapred.MapTask: mapreduce.task.io.sort.mb: 100
16/06/07 14:49:24 INFO mapred.MapTask: soft limit at 83886080
16/06/07 14:49:24 INFO mapred.MapTask: bufstart = 0; bufvoid = 104857600
16/06/07 14:49:24 INFO mapred.MapTask: kvstart = 26214396; length = 6553600
16/06/07 14:49:24 INFO mapred.MapTask: Map output collector class = org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer
16/06/07 14:49:25 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_local1881318657_0001 running in uber mode : false
16/06/07 14:49:25 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
16/06/07 14:49:31 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: map > map
16/06/07 14:49:31 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 22% reduce 0%
-3.042421771435325E-9
-3.042421771435325E-9
-3.042421771435325E-9
-3.042421771435325E-9
-3.042421771435325E-9
-2.9889415942690763E-9
-2.9889415942690763E-9
-2.9889415942690763E-9
-2.9287384547432996E-9
-2.898469757139896E-9
-2.898469757139896E-9
-2.880377562441664E-9
-2.880377562441664E-9
-2.880377562441664E-9
-2.8430632294667886E-9
-2.819146987128837E-9
-2.819146987128837E-9
-2.819146987128837E-9
-2.819146987128837E-9
-2.819146987128837E-9
931
16/06/07 15:00:44 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: map > map
16/06/07 15:00:44 INFO mapred.MapTask: Starting flush of map output
16/06/07 15:00:44 INFO mapred.MapTask: Spilling map output
16/06/07 15:00:44 INFO mapred.MapTask: bufstart = 0; bufend = 14151; bufvoid = 104857600
16/06/07 15:00:44 INFO mapred.MapTask: kvstart = 26214396(104857584); kvend = 26214396(104857584); length = 1/6553600
16/06/07 15:00:46 INFO mapred.MapTask: Finished spill 0
16/06/07 15:00:46 INFO mapred.Task: Task:attempt_local1881318657_0001_m_000000_0 is done. And is in the process of committing
16/06/07 15:00:47 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: map
16/06/07 15:00:47 INFO mapred.Task: Task 'attempt_local1881318657_0001_m_000000_0' done.
16/06/07 15:00:47 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Finishing task: attempt_local1881318657_0001_m_000000_0
16/06/07 15:00:47 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Starting task: attempt_local1881318657_0001_m_000001_0
16/06/07 15:00:48 INFO mapred.Task:  Using ResourceCalculatorProcessTree : [ ]
16/06/07 15:00:48 INFO mapred.MapTask: Processing split: hdfs://master:9000/input/leukemia1.txt:0+1172207
16/06/07 15:00:48 INFO mapred.MapTask: (EQUATOR) 0 kvi 26214396(104857584)
16/06/07 15:00:48 INFO mapred.MapTask: mapreduce.task.io.sort.mb: 100
16/06/07 15:00:48 INFO mapred.MapTask: soft limit at 83886080
16/06/07 15:00:48 INFO mapred.MapTask: bufstart = 0; bufvoid = 104857600
16/06/07 15:00:48 INFO mapred.MapTask: kvstart = 26214396; length = 6553600
16/06/07 15:00:48 INFO mapred.MapTask: Map output collector class = org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer
16/06/07 15:00:48 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 0%
16/06/07 15:01:47 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: map > map
16/06/07 15:01:48 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 56% reduce 0%
-3.0279963370711145E-9
-3.0279963370711145E-9
-3.0279963370711145E-9
-3.0279963370711145E-9
-3.0279963370711145E-9
-3.001716001136338E-9
-2.997252637652067E-9
-2.997252637652067E-9
-2.9593407930592893E-9
-2.9178102507568847E-9
-2.9178102507568847E-9
-2.9178102507568847E-9
-2.8542232742481287E-9
-2.8542232742481287E-9
-2.8510431833778047E-9
-2.8510431833778047E-9
-2.8510431833778047E-9
-2.8510431833778047E-9
-2.8222418341121026E-9
-2.8222418341121026E-9
907
16/06/07 15:11:30 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: map > map
16/06/07 15:11:30 INFO mapred.MapTask: Starting flush of map output
16/06/07 15:11:30 INFO mapred.MapTask: Spilling map output
16/06/07 15:11:30 INFO mapred.MapTask: bufstart = 0; bufend = 14151; bufvoid = 104857600
16/06/07 15:11:30 INFO mapred.MapTask: kvstart = 26214396(104857584); kvend = 26214396(104857584); length = 1/6553600
16/06/07 15:11:30 INFO mapred.MapTask: Finished spill 0
16/06/07 15:11:30 INFO mapred.Task: Task:attempt_local1881318657_0001_m_000001_0 is done. And is in the process of committing
16/06/07 15:11:30 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: map
16/06/07 15:11:30 INFO mapred.Task: Task 'attempt_local1881318657_0001_m_000001_0' done.
16/06/07 15:11:30 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Finishing task: attempt_local1881318657_0001_m_000001_0
16/06/07 15:11:30 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Starting task: attempt_local1881318657_0001_m_000002_0
16/06/07 15:11:30 INFO mapred.Task:  Using ResourceCalculatorProcessTree : [ ]
16/06/07 15:11:30 INFO mapred.MapTask: Processing split: hdfs://master:9000/input/leukemia2.txt:0+1172207
16/06/07 15:11:30 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 0%
16/06/07 15:11:31 INFO mapred.MapTask: (EQUATOR) 0 kvi 26214396(104857584)
16/06/07 15:11:31 INFO mapred.MapTask: mapreduce.task.io.sort.mb: 100
16/06/07 15:11:31 INFO mapred.MapTask: soft limit at 83886080
16/06/07 15:11:31 INFO mapred.MapTask: bufstart = 0; bufvoid = 104857600
16/06/07 15:11:31 INFO mapred.MapTask: kvstart = 26214396; length = 6553600
16/06/07 15:11:31 INFO mapred.MapTask: Map output collector class = org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer
16/06/07 15:11:37 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: map > map
16/06/07 15:11:38 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 89% reduce 0%
-3.064963887619912E-9
-3.064963887619912E-9
-3.064963887619912E-9
-3.064963887619912E-9
-3.064963887619912E-9
-3.0090989883906007E-9
-2.9474075636124447E-9
-2.9474075636124447E-9
-2.9474075636124447E-9
-2.9388849943338927E-9
-2.9388849943338927E-9
-2.8915704649620403E-9
-2.8102046711682226E-9
-2.8102046711682226E-9
-2.8102046711682226E-9
-2.8102046711682226E-9
-2.8102046711682226E-9
-2.8102046711682226E-9
-2.8102046711682226E-9
-2.8102046711682226E-9 
925
16/06/07 15:20:19 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: map > map
16/06/07 15:20:19 INFO mapred.MapTask: Starting flush of map output
16/06/07 15:20:19 INFO mapred.MapTask: Spilling map output
16/06/07 15:20:19 INFO mapred.MapTask: bufstart = 0; bufend = 14151; bufvoid = 104857600
16/06/07 15:20:19 INFO mapred.MapTask: kvstart = 26214396(104857584); kvend = 26214396(104857584); length = 1/6553600
16/06/07 15:20:20 INFO mapred.MapTask: Finished spill 0
16/06/07 15:20:20 INFO mapred.Task: Task:attempt_local1881318657_0001_m_000002_0 is done. And is in the process of committing
16/06/07 15:20:22 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: map
16/06/07 15:20:22 INFO mapred.Task: Task 'attempt_local1881318657_0001_m_000002_0' done.
16/06/07 15:20:22 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Finishing task: attempt_local1881318657_0001_m_000002_0
16/06/07 15:20:22 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: map task executor complete.
16/06/07 15:20:22 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 0%
16/06/07 15:20:23 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Waiting for reduce tasks
16/06/07 15:20:23 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Starting task: attempt_local1881318657_0001_r_000000_0
16/06/07 15:20:24 INFO mapred.Task:  Using ResourceCalculatorProcessTree : [ ]
16/06/07 15:20:24 INFO mapred.ReduceTask: Using ShuffleConsumerPlugin: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.Shuffle@7f5be2d5
16/06/07 15:20:25 INFO reduce.MergeManagerImpl: MergerManager: memoryLimit=668309888, maxSingleShuffleLimit=167077472, mergeThreshold=441084544, ioSortFactor=10, memToMemMergeOutputsThreshold=10
16/06/07 15:20:25 INFO reduce.EventFetcher: attempt_local1881318657_0001_r_000000_0 Thread started: EventFetcher for fetching Map Completion Events
16/06/07 15:20:28 INFO reduce.LocalFetcher: localfetcher#1 about to shuffle output of map attempt_local1881318657_0001_m_000002_0 decomp: 14157 len: 14161 to MEMORY
16/06/07 15:20:29 INFO reduce.InMemoryMapOutput: Read 14157 bytes from map-output for attempt_local1881318657_0001_m_000002_0
16/06/07 15:20:30 INFO reduce.MergeManagerImpl: closeInMemoryFile -> map-output of size: 14157, inMemoryMapOutputs.size() -> 1, commitMemory -> 0, usedMemory ->14157
16/06/07 15:20:30 INFO reduce.LocalFetcher: localfetcher#1 about to shuffle output of map attempt_local1881318657_0001_m_000001_0 decomp: 14157 len: 14161 to MEMORY
16/06/07 15:20:30 INFO reduce.InMemoryMapOutput: Read 14157 bytes from map-output for attempt_local1881318657_0001_m_000001_0
16/06/07 15:20:30 INFO reduce.MergeManagerImpl: closeInMemoryFile -> map-output of size: 14157, inMemoryMapOutputs.size() -> 2, commitMemory -> 14157, usedMemory ->28314
16/06/07 15:20:30 INFO reduce.LocalFetcher: localfetcher#1 about to shuffle output of map attempt_local1881318657_0001_m_000000_0 decomp: 14157 len: 14161 to MEMORY
16/06/07 15:20:30 INFO reduce.InMemoryMapOutput: Read 14157 bytes from map-output for attempt_local1881318657_0001_m_000000_0
16/06/07 15:20:30 INFO reduce.MergeManagerImpl: closeInMemoryFile -> map-output of size: 14157, inMemoryMapOutputs.size() -> 3, commitMemory -> 28314, usedMemory ->42471
16/06/07 15:20:30 INFO reduce.EventFetcher: EventFetcher is interrupted.. Returning
16/06/07 15:20:30 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: 3 / 3 copied.
16/06/07 15:20:30 INFO reduce.MergeManagerImpl: finalMerge called with 3 in-memory map-outputs and 0 on-disk map-outputs
16/06/07 15:20:30 INFO mapred.Merger: Merging 3 sorted segments
16/06/07 15:20:30 INFO mapred.Merger: Down to the last merge-pass, with 3 segments left of total size: 42435 bytes
16/06/07 15:20:30 INFO reduce.MergeManagerImpl: Merged 3 segments, 42471 bytes to disk to satisfy reduce memory limit
16/06/07 15:20:30 INFO reduce.MergeManagerImpl: Merging 1 files, 42471 bytes from disk
16/06/07 15:20:30 INFO reduce.MergeManagerImpl: Merging 0 segments, 0 bytes from memory into reduce
16/06/07 15:20:30 INFO mapred.Merger: Merging 1 sorted segments
16/06/07 15:20:30 INFO mapred.Merger: Down to the last merge-pass, with 1 segments left of total size: 42455 bytes
16/06/07 15:20:30 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: 3 / 3 copied.
16/06/07 15:20:33 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: reduce > reduce
16/06/07 15:20:33 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 67%
16/06/07 15:20:36 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: reduce > reduce
16/06/07 15:20:38 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.skip.on is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.skiprecords
16/06/07 15:20:42 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: reduce > reduce
16/06/07 15:20:42 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 100%
16/06/07 15:20:44 INFO mapred.Task: Task:attempt_local1881318657_0001_r_000000_0 is done. And is in the process of committing
16/06/07 15:20:44 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: reduce > reduce
16/06/07 15:20:44 INFO mapred.Task: Task attempt_local1881318657_0001_r_000000_0 is allowed to commit now
16/06/07 15:20:45 INFO output.FileOutputCommitter: Saved output of task 'attempt_local1881318657_0001_r_000000_0' to hdfs://master:9000/output2/_temporary/0/task_local1881318657_0001_r_000000
16/06/07 15:20:45 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: reduce > reduce
16/06/07 15:20:45 INFO mapred.Task: Task 'attempt_local1881318657_0001_r_000000_0' done.
16/06/07 15:20:45 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Finishing task: attempt_local1881318657_0001_r_000000_0
16/06/07 15:20:45 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: reduce task executor complete.
16/06/07 15:20:45 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_local1881318657_0001 completed successfully
16/06/07 15:20:46 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 38
    File System Counters
        FILE: Number of bytes read=177067554
        FILE: Number of bytes written=179551452
        FILE: Number of read operations=0
        FILE: Number of large read operations=0
        FILE: Number of write operations=0
        HDFS: Number of bytes read=10549863
        HDFS: Number of bytes written=42438
        HDFS: Number of read operations=37
        HDFS: Number of large read operations=0
        HDFS: Number of write operations=6
    Map-Reduce Framework
        Map input records=3
        Map output records=3
        Map output bytes=42453
        Map output materialized bytes=42483
        Input split bytes=557
        Combine input records=0
        Combine output records=0
        Reduce input groups=2
        Reduce shuffle bytes=42483
        Reduce input records=3
        Reduce output records=3
        Spilled Records=6
        Shuffled Maps =3
        Failed Shuffles=0
        Merged Map outputs=3
        GC time elapsed (ms)=227283
        CPU time spent (ms)=0
        Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=0
        Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=0
        Total committed heap usage (bytes)=2477260800
    Shuffle Errors
        BAD_ID=0
        CONNECTION=0
        IO_ERROR=0
        WRONG_LENGTH=0
        WRONG_MAP=0
        WRONG_REDUCE=0
    File Input Format Counters 
        Bytes Read=0
    File Output Format Counters 
        Bytes Written=42438
```

peace

Answer (score 1):

By the job ID. Your's says: `job_local1881318657_0001 running in uber mode : false`. Which is a local job. If you ran on a cluster it would just be the job and the identifiers of the app master and attempts.

Comment: thanx for ur answer, but if u could help me to fix it cus i realy dont know what to do

Comment: @saibbouthina do what exactly?

Comment: i mean my cluster is well configured but my jobs are run in local how to fix it so it excute in parallel .

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the JobTracker ( default port 50030) and explore the job id details mentioned in the above logs.

Answer (score 0):

You can monitor the jobs at:

> localhost:8088